# How pass environment variables in the container using Dockerfile but with a separate file for environment variables like .env

Tags: docker, docker-compose, environment-variables, dockerfile, containers

So I am stuck at this problem for quite a while now.

I know that we should write our code as such that at any time we can make the project open source without compromising on the confidential aspects.

So, I seem to understand that it is not advisable to define the Environment Variables directly in either Dockerfile or docker-compose.yml, rather we should define all of them in a separate file such as **.env**.

Now, I know that we can use `docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml --env-file=.env up`  when dealing with docker-compose.

I want to know the following two things:

1. How to deal things with Dockerfile from build to run (the environment variables file part, like `--env-file`)
2. Should we build images with already defined environment variables in it and then share the image with others so that they don't have to get bothered by redefining environment variables at the time of running the image, or should build a generic image and then let the user define the environment variables as they may please. What is considered the best practice?

Can someone also comment on the following (using Dockerfile)

#### Method 1:

**example_Dockerfile**:

```
FROM python:latest

# many other steps in between

RUN printf 'key=21345' > config

ENTRYPOINT ["./boot.sh"]
```

Steps to build and run:

1. `docker build -f example_Dockerfile -t my_container .`
2. `docker run --env-file=example.env my_container`

I know that Method 1 is correct but I want to know if something like Method 2 (following) can be done.

#### Method 2:

**example_Dockerfile**:

```
FROM python:latest

# many other steps in between 

RUN printf 'key=${KEY}' > config

ENTRYPOINT ["./boot.sh"]
```

**example.env**:

```
# many other environment variables

KEY = 21345
```

It would be awesome if you can also provide the command steps to build and run the container in this method to do this.

The main difference in the two methods is that that in Method 2, I have defined the **KEY** variable in a **.env** file and am wanting to somehow integrate that in the **Dockerfile** (by using `${KEY}` as we do in **docker-compose.yml**) without mentioning that value in the **Dockerfile**

I would be really grateful if someone could explain by giving an example for both of the above points.

Thanks a lot in advanced.

Answer (score 0):

This usecase has 2 aspects:

- if environment vars are required only for build, better use docker build arg. Build args works same as env vars but only during `docker build`, they are not packaged in final image. For more check this [link](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/#set-build-time-variables---build-arg).

  - `docker build --build-arg VAR_A=val_a -f Dockerfile .`
  - Dockerfile

    ```
    FROM python:3.7-slim
    ARG VAR_A
    RUN echo $VAR_A
    ```
- in some cases environment vars are generic and required for runtime, you can safely package them using `ENV` instruction in Dockerfile

---

**[Bonus Tip]** - best avoid using `latest` image tag with `FROM` instruction in Dockerfile because this makes it hard to track which version of the image is running and hard to roll back.

Answer (score 0):

My general experience has been that it's preferable to use environment variables for settings that can (or should or must) be changed at run time, but that's preferable to other mechanisms like command-line arguments or config files.  This includes things like the host names of other services you depend on.  A typical minimal `docker-compose.yml` setup might look like:

```yaml
version: '3.8'
services:
  app:
    build: .
    ports: ['8080:8080']
    environment:
      - REDIS_HOST=redis
      - PUBLIC_URL=http://example.com/
  redis:
    image: redis:6.0
```

I tend to minimize environment variables in my Dockerfile.  You hint at some confidentiality concerns in the question; anyone who has an image can `docker inspect` it or `docker run --rm imagename env` and dump them out, regardless of how they were added; a build-time `.env` file wouldn't help anything.  In other SO questions I see variables used for filesystem paths or ports, but these don't need to be changed at runtime.

```sh
# Avoid setting filesystem paths or ports as environment variables:
ENV APP_DIR=/app
COPY . $APP_DIR
RUN chmod +x $APP_DIR/entrypoint.sh
ENV PORT=8080
EXPOSE $PORT
```

```sh
# It's fine to hard-code these values, and use relative paths:
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
RUN chmod +x entrypoint.sh
EXPOSE 8080
```

```sh
# No matter what, the container will always be run as
docker run -v $PWD/data:/app/data -p 8080:8080 imagename
# and changing the build-time environment variables has no effect
```

Style-wise, it's a little better to make the Dockerfile as simple as possible (but no simpler).  If you have a config file with fixed keys and fixed values, don't try generating it in the Dockerfile; maintain it directly on disk, possibly with a different name if it makes sense for you.

```sh
# Don't RUN echo ... > file; instead just
COPY config.docker.yaml ./config.yaml
```

The flip side of this is that it's not required to set environment variables, so you need to tolerate something being unset.  The pattern I've found helpful is to guess that if a program is being run directly, it's by a developer who won't have manually configured things, and if it's being run in a container, automation like Compose or Kubernetes will provide the environment variables for you.

```py
# Check that $PUBLIC_URL is set
public_url = os.environ.get('PUBLIC_URL')
if public_url is None:
    print('Please set $PUBLIC_URL environment variable')
    os.exit(1)

# Get the Redis host, or assume a developer environment
redis_host = os.environ.get('REDIS_HOST', 'localhost')
```

I said up front that I'd prefer directly using environment variables over config files.  The outputs of your examples 1 and 2 are identical because the config file is fixed at build time.  If you need to recreate a config file based on environment variables, you have to do this in an entrypoint script when your container starts up.  A typical example might use the GNU [envsubst](https://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/html_node/envsubst-Invocation.html) tool (which won't be preinstalled on Alpine-based images) to rewrite it:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
# Rewrite the config file
envsubst < config.tmpl > config
# Switch over to the main container process
exec "$@"
```

```sh
# ENTRYPOINT _must_ be JSON-array syntax for this
ENTRYPOINT ["./entrypoint.sh"]
CMD ["./boot.sh"]
```

`envsubst` replaces shell-style `$ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE` references in files, so the `config.tmpl` file here could look like

```
key=$KEY
```